# Array loop to get single value

Tags: javascript

If i have data in a json formate,

```js
"contactNo":[

{
  "number"      : "864 643-0563",
  "type"            : "mobile"
},
{
  "number"      : "864 643-7767",
  "type"            : "mobile"
}],
```

how to retrive number only from 1st array?? 
i tried to get the values like this...

```js
for(var i=0;i<type.contactNo[0].length;i++){
var j=type.contactNo[0].number;
console.log("number:  "+j);
}
```

type is my object...
but it is returning contactNo undifined!!! Do help *Thanks in advance*

Comment: Why `loop` ? `type.contactNo[0].number`

Comment: same prob contactNo undefined..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It got resolved while changing dataset values into...

```js
    contactNo        : [{
      contacNumber         : String,
      contacType           : String
    }],
```

Answer (score 0):

> but it is returning contactNo undefined!!!

`type.contactNo[0].length` is `undefined` since `type.contactNo[0]` is not an array, it is an object.

Replace your for loop with

```
for(var i=0;i<type.contactNo;i++){
  var j=type.contactNo[i].number;
  console.log("number:  "+j);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You don't need to use a loop.**

You could just

`console.log("Number: " + type.contactNo[0].number);`